# Что такое r и x в алгоритме протоколирования упрощённого калькулятора?

Tags: c#, калькулятор

Пытаюсь разобраться в алгоритме протоколирования (в ListBox) и подсчёта калькулятора, но не понимаю одну вещь. По идее у нас есть r-первое число, вводимое пользователем, и x-второе число вводимое пользователем. Но почему в примере, который я приведу, мы нигде не поясняем программе что такое r?  **В том смысле**, что **x = double.Parse(t0.Text);** у нас есть, а **r = double.Parse(t0.Text);** нет нигде, хотя r-первое вводимое число. Как тогда она понимает, что r-это первое введённое пользователем число? Также, как Вы видите в конце функции, мы добавляем в ListBox x, но при первом нажатии пользователя на кнопку какой-либо вычислительной операции, второго операнда (x, как я понимаю) ещё нет, но тем не менее он выводится в ListBox исправно, хоть пока и без знака операции. Ниже приведено всё, что нужно калькулятору для счёта и протоколирования, ранее в коде про r и x речи не было.

**Вот сама функция:**

```
        double r = 0;
        double x = 0;
        char op = ' ';

        void calculate()
        {
            x = double.Parse(t0.Text);  
            t0.Clear();
            switch (op)
            {
                case '+':
                    r = x + r;
                    break;
                case '-':
                    r = r - x;
                    break;
                case '/':
                    r = r / x;
                    break;
                case '*':
                    r = r * x;
                    break;
                default:
                    r = x;
                    break;
            }

            l0.Items.Add(op.ToString());
            l0.Items.Add(x);
        }
```

А вот ещё код кнопки, меняющий знак введённого числа, и тут тоже фигурирует x, а не r: (хотя можно сменить знак у первого введённого числа, которое по идее=r)

```
void b17_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //КНОПКА СМЕНЫ ЗНАКА
        {
            double x = double.Parse(t0.Text);
            x = x * (-1);
            t0.Text = " ";
            t0.Text = x.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: это названия переменных, вы их можете обозвать как хотите, хоть r, хоть x, хоть вася или петя.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

r - это регистр калькулятора. По сути, просто переменная.

Действие (двухместная операция) производится над регистром и числом.

Операция ввода (без арифметической операции) же назначает регистру введённое значение

```
default:
       r = x;
```

`меняющий знак введённого числа` - это одноместная операция, тут второй операнд не нужен

Comment: Я считал, что default срабатывает, если не был затронут ни один из case'ов. Получается default срабатывает если не была нажата ни одна операция? То есть, когда мы только вводим первое число срабатывает default?

Comment: default  срабатывает, если выбрана операция, не входящая в список четырёх арифметических. Например, `"="` нажато

Comment: Но всё-таки, откуда программа получает значение r для арифметических операций, например r=r-x, если у нас перед этим в функции было только  **x = double.Parse(t0.Text)**? Где получает саоё числовое значение r? Ведь между тем, что double r=0 и действием между r и x ничего не происходит

Comment: Если ввели какое-то значение, то в r оно, иначе 0. Запустите виндовый калькулятор. Он показывает 0. Введите "+5". Вычислится 0+5=5

Comment: Да, я понимаю, что должно быть так, но где это указано в программе? Где указано, что r-это введённое значение? Я просто вижу только присвоение значения x, а где что-то присваивается r я не вижу. Вот ввёл пользователь первое число, допустим 123, и, если судить по коду, то 123-это x=double.Parse(t0.Text). А r где тут? Простите, пока не понимаю до конца

Comment: На каждом шаге у вас есть регистр/переменная r (c начальным 0), введённая переменная x, и откуда-то взятая операция. Любая операция приводит к изменению r. `а где что-то присваивается r я не вижу` Присвоение r в коде встречается **5 раз**